# Solow long run growth model question

Tags: macroeconomics

I've been stuck on an exam question regarding long run growth

Consider the following model of economic growth

[image]

A) Derive the equilibrium growth rate of capital, and hence find the steady-state values
of capital and output.

If there is no $K_t$ term in (4) how does one find the growth rate? Since the growth is found using $\Delta K/K_t \equiv \frac {Kt+1 - Kt} {Kt}$.

Comment: Are you sure that equation $(4)$ is correct? In absence of depreciation we should have $\Delta  K= K_{t+1}-K_t=I_t$. An equation as $(4)$ implies that the capital stock of the preceding period $K_t$ is $0$, so that in each period the existing stock of capital is destroyed. It could be, even if it s  unusual.

Comment: Moreover, how is the steady state defined here? In the usual Solow model it is the state in which the capital-labor ratio remains constant, but here we haven’t any information about population growth and per capita variables.  I suppose $\Delta K=0$

Comment: @BakerStreet Yes I copied it straight from the past paper, it's unusual as no other questions given to me have depreciation and/or Kt missing. 

The steady state is defined as DeltaKt+1 = 0.

Comment: Ok, the absence of $K_t$ is not a problem, I give my suggestions in an answer below.

Comment: Those equations could perhaps model a primitive agricultural economy with seed retained from one year to the next as the only capital, also output less than proportional to seed input because of a limited supply of land and/or labour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the **rate of growth  of capital** just subtract $K_t$ from both sides of $(4)$, to obtain:

$$\Delta K\equiv K_{t+1}-K_t= I_t-K_t \qquad (1)$$

from which, recalling equality of investment and saving

$$\frac {\Delta K}{K_t}= \frac {I_t-K_t}{K_t}   =\frac {sA{K_t}^{1/2}- K_t}{K_t}\qquad (2)$$ .

You can find the **steady state value of capital and output**, defined as a state in which the stock of capital is constant,  setting the preceding equation equal to $0$:

$$\frac {\Delta K}{K_t}= \frac {sA{K_t}^{1/2}- K_t}{K_t}=0\qquad (3)$$

From $(3)$ you obtain the steady state value of $K_t$ and then you can derive the steady state value of output plugging this value of $K_t$  into the production function as usual.

Comment: Thats very helpful, thanks! In the second line, why didn't you divide by the Kt to cancel out Kt/Kt and reduce Kt^1/2 to Kt^-1/2?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, it is the same. You can do the steps you prefer to find the solution.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Hey, one more question. How would I go about deriving the saving rate that maximises the steady state consumption?

Comment: Find the steady state consumption using equation $(3)$, in terms of the saving rate $s$, then maximize it with respect to $s$.

Comment: So I simply replace the LHS with the value of Y*(steady state), It with sYt, then substitute the Yt with the steady state value of Y?

Then differentiate with respect to s?

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly what you said, I don't understand what is LHS.  From $(3)$ you have $C_t=Y_t-I_t$, then  sostitute saving for $I_t$, all considered at their steady state vaues.

Comment: LHS = Left hand side but yes that's what I referring to, many thanks again

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> Are you sure that equation (4)
> is correct? In absence of depreciation we should have ΔK=Kt+1−Kt=It
> . An equation as (4)
> implies that the capital stock of the preceding period Kt
> is 0
> , so that in each period the existing stock of capital is destroyed. It could be, even if it s unusual.

It must be that the depreciation rate is 100% indeed.

Comment: Yes, it is the same, capital 'disappears' for some reason. It is a possible assumption, all models are not realistic to some extent. Just, to answer the question, one must be sure that the text is correct and there aren't typos.

Comment: I thought so but I'm not sure if it's right, or how to go about solving it.

Comment: Looking  for a solution is possible even if $(4)$ is correct.

Comment: @BakerStreet How would I go about it?

Comment: I write my suggestions in an answer

Comment: Why the downvote? It is just an observation, correct, a possible formalization, it is not wrong.